# Web Site Framework

Tags: user-interface, javascript-framework

I'm putting together somewhat of a social website. It's not another social network, but it is a site to be used in a social setting (non-professional). It's going to need to be very simple, but I would like it to have a spark of flair as well.

Think a mixture of twitter and chatroulette (not for the functionality but the style). The simplicity of chatroulette but the flair of Twitter.

Here's my issue. I was putting the UI together a few nights ago, and I was using JQuery UI elements to create it. It just felt too....professional. I really don't know how to explain it. The JQGrid is something that looks like it's meant to be in a CRM at a huge software company, all of the accordion/buttons/tabbed elements look like they should all be in a enterprise web app. I just don't get that "friendly/casual" feel from JQuery UI.

The same issue with ExtJs as well. I'm TERRIBLE with CSS and Photoshop however, which is why I was looking to some JS frameworks in the first place for UI on my site.

Do you guys know of any cool frameworks or anything where I can add that friendly look without going too professional, and that I preferably don't have to build up myself =/

Thanks guys.

Comment: "a mixture of twitter and chatroulette" ... the mind boggles.

Comment: Just stylistic wise, not functionality, lol. I want to maintain that simplistic feel of chatroulette but also that stylistic feel of twitter. I more meant how the user feels when visiting each site, not the exact look.

Comment: You can roll your own jQuery-UI theme and make it look pretty much any way want.

Comment: @mu : i wouldn't know the first place to start, lol. I know there are different themes, but as far as creating my own or customizing the elements, I've never done those things before. Is there any resources out there?

Comment: There is some documentation on rolling your own themes on jqueryui.com: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming and http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API look like good starting points.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into these and see what I can do. Anyone else?

Comment: Hmmm looks like a popular idea - I just released something just like it.  [Zazzer.me](http://zazzer.me).  I used Dojo to build mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't feel like re-inventing the wheel, what about using an available framework like Ning?

http://www.ning.com/

Although I've never used it myself, I know some startups done with it and it seems to meet their requirements.

Remember that most of the times it's best to start small. Get something working first and then move on to perfectionism.